# RAILS 5 Javascript not working on remote true method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Im trying to render a create.js.erb on Rails 5 when I call create action of comments on my app, I can't get it to work and I'm running out of time, I will really thank your help. This is my code:

**My Comments_Controller (part of it):**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, :set_replies, only: [:show, :edit, :update,:destroy]
  before_action :set_congress, :set_category, :set_presentation
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  respond_to :js, :html
  layout "insideapplication"
  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])
  end

 def create
   @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
   @comment.author_id = current_user.id
   @comment.presentation = @presentation

   respond_to  do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to  [@congress, @category, @presentation],notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
        format.js 
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js 
      end
    end
  end
```

**My index.html.erb (Comments)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="text-center">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mynewpost">
            New Post
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <hr>
    <div class="row" id="container_posts">
        <%= render @posts %>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal  create action -->
      <%= form_for(@post, remote: true) do |f| %>
          <div class="modal fade" id="mynewpost" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Post</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :title %><br>
                <%= f.text_area :title, class: "form-control post_title" %>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :content %><br>
                <%= f.text_area :content, class: "form-control post_content" %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="mynewpostclose">Close</button>
              <%= submit_tag "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <!-- Modal -->
</div>
```

**My create.js.erb (testing js only)**

```
alert("test!!!");
```

Comment: Also no errors on console

Comment: What happens when you submit the form?

Comment: it refresh the page and create the comment, everything fine but the .js.erb whis is ignored completely

Comment: It must be a `jquery-ujs` issue then, that it what handles `remote: true` in Rails.

Comment: added into the used layout, still nothing

Answer (score 0):

This seams to be a Windows related error, I moved my code to Ubuntu and now .js.erb files works perfectly